# SQL Error executing INSERT: [SQLITE_BUSY] The database file is locked

Tags: sqlite, connection, primary-key, unique-constraint, micronaut

I am using sqlite as db in my Micronaut application getting the sqlite busy error in the below code:

```
    @SneakyThrows
    @TransactionalAdvice(value = EmpDao.DATASOURCE, propagation = TransactionDefinition.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void storeEmp(EmpDto empDto) {
        String id = empDto.getId();
        try {
            if (empDao.existsById(id)) {
                log.debug("updating emp for id {}", empDto.getId());
                empDao.update(EmpEntity.builder()
                        .id(id)
                        .data(getJson(empDto))
                        .entryCreatedAt(timeService.nowDateTime().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC))
                        .build());
            } else {
                empDao.save(
                           EmpEntity.builder()
                        .id(id)
                        .data(getJson(empDto))
                        .entryCreatedAt(timeService.nowDateTime().toEpochSecond(ZoneOffset.UTC))
                        .build());
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.error("emp db save/update failed for id {} ",id, e);
        }
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    @TransactionalAdvice(value = EmpDao.DATASOURCE, propagation = TransactionDefinition.Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void storeEmployees(List<Emp> empDtos) {
        try {
            empDao.saveAll(empDto);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.warn("saveAll failed", ex);
            empDtos.forEach(this::storeEmp);
        }
    }
```

In stacktrace I can see first `saveAll` getting failed becuase of Primary keyconstraint Issue, that might be because of duplicate emp ids in the list

```
SQL error executing INSERT: [SQLITE_CONSTRAINT_PRIMARYKEY]  A PRIMARY KEY constraint failed
```

and After that when It tried to save/update each emp object independently through storeEmp method in forEach, it's failing with the sqlite busy exception.

What I am not sure if saveAll is already failed, how there can be multiple connection to sqlite. Can anyone suggest what's wrong with the above code.

Thanks